# Is real number natural?

Tags: numbers, pascal, division

I have 2 real numbers ( e.g. a , b). Is there any way to know whether is their division's result  natural number? 
I have tried

```
a mod b  {to check if the result is 0}
```

but "mod" doesn't work for real numbers.
Also

```
a/b-trunc(a/b) {but sometimes the answer isn't 0}
```

I'm beginner, please, whether is there any other way, let me know.

Comment: Why don't you directly test for "frac"? Anyway, it doesn't have to be 0, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Representable_numbers,_conversion_and_rounding .

Comment: *`a/b-trunc(a/b)` {but sometimes the answer isn't 0}*. Well, if the answer isn't zero, that's some indication that the result of `a/b` may not be a natural number, right? Although you'll need to keep in mind there's a bit of margin of error with dealing with floats. So a quotient might, in theory, but 3, but come out as 2.999999 and `trunc` will give 2. You have to account for that somehow. Representation of floats in a computer isn't exact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Frac` could be one idea as @Sertac mentions. But since binary floating point does not represent all real numbers, there could be cases where the fraction could end up close to zero (or one for that matter) as well.

Here is a simple routine that avoids testing for both close to one or zero:

```
function IsNaturalNumber( value : Double) : Boolean;
const
  epsilon : Double = 1E-12;
begin
  IsNaturalNumber := Abs(value - Round(value)) < epsilon;
end;

var
  A,B : Double;
begin
  A := 3.3;
  B := 1.1;
  WriteLn(IsNaturalNumber(A/B));  // Writes TRUE
end.
```

The function tests if the absolute difference between the value and the value rounded to nearest integer is smaller than a reasonable limit.

*Note that there is no absolute certainty. That would require using a decimal floating point arithmetic library.*

---

I will leave it up to the interested reader to implement the exclusion of integer numbers that is outside the range of the natural numbers, whether that is all negative numbers including zero or not.

---

If the values to test are larger than the upper range of the `Round()` function, use an equivalent floating point function. In Delphi that is `Math.RoundTo(value,0)`.